# Running applications with custom %APPDATA% and %PROGRAMDATA% variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've been trying to run a application with a custom %PROGRAMDATA% and %APPDATA% variable but so far I had no luck.

Here is my code:

```
set "%PROGRAMDATA% = E:\Electronic*Arts\"
set "%APPDATA% = E:\Electronic*Arts\AppData"
start "" "GameLauncher.exe"
```

Also I forgot to mention, it would be nice if this worked with shortcuts as well.

Comment: What about it did not work? Please note that there are more ways to get to ProgramData and AppData, that do not entail looking at the environment values. See for instance `SHGetFolderPath` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @MicroVirus it got answered by MC ND by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal 
set "PROGRAMDATA=E:\Electronic*Arts\"
set "APPDATA=E:\Electronic*Arts\AppData"
start "" "GameLauncher.exe"
endlocal
```

`%var%` syntax is used to retrieve the content of the variable.

Save the lines in a batch file and create the shortcut to point to the batch file.

`setlocal` / `endlocal` just ensures the changes are not visible from outside of the block of code if you call the batch file from a command line window.

Comment: Thank you! My Need for Speed installation is now portable :) also I hope nothing happen cause I forgot about the setlocal and endlocal

Comment: Nope! Its all up and working and nothing changed in the system :D